# SQL reading from a comma delimited field and then bringing data back in comma delimited format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in string format `3,2,1` in a table column. I have lookup table that tells me the file name associated to the file

Table looks like this

```
Id (int) name
------------------
  1      file 1
  2      file 2
```

What I want to do is send the string `3,2,1` and get data back as `file 1, file 2` as a separate column so I can refer it in displaying. Mind you that this will be addition into the existing stored procedure that's why I only want one string row back

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Do yourself a favor and stop storing multiple discrete items in the same column. It breaks the relational model and is a really bad practice.

Comment: Here is another fine example illustraiting that keeping delimited data in a relational database column should be outlawed.

Comment: Thank you captain obvious. Sometimes you get stuck with someone else's code and if you cant contriburte please shut up and get a life

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write some code like this. The below code it's just an example to put you on the right track. Let me know if you have any questions

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @index1 INT
DECLARE @index2 INT
DECLARE @Id VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @input = '3,2,1';
SET @str = REVERSE(@input)
SET @index1 = 1;
SET @index2 = CHARINDEX(',', @str)
SET @Id = SUBSTRING(@str, @index1, @index2 -@index1)

SET @result = 'File ' + @Id + ','

WHILE (@index2 > 0 )
BEGIN

    SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str, @index2 + 1, LEN(@str) -@index1)
    SET @Id = SUBSTRING(@str,@index1,@index2 -@index1) 
    SET @index1 = @index2
    SET @index2 = CHARINDEX(',', @str)
    IF LEN(@Id) > 0
        SET @result = @result + 'File ' + @Id + ','
END

SET @Id = @str;
SET @result =  @result + 'File ' + @Id

SELECT @result
```

Comment: Thank you i will try it but the problem is this @input variable you mentioned is coming form a different database table I am more looking towards one or 2 liner code that will do the join and spit out the field so I can use it in my out put field. Hope I made things little more clear then they were but appreciate you taking time to help me

Comment: You can get the input variable from the database table

Replace the line
>SET input ='3,2,1'
by 
>SET input = ( SELECT TargetField FROM TargetDb.TargetTable)

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
-- Create ID String, only used for example
DECLARE @IDString varchar(max)
set @IDString = '1,2,3,4'

-- Create lookup table, only used for example
CREATE TABLE #lookup (id int, val varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #lookup(id, val) VALUES (1, 'first lookup') 
INSERT INTO #lookup(id, val) VALUES (2, 'second lookup') 
INSERT INTO #lookup(id, val) VALUES (3, 'third lookup') 
INSERT INTO #lookup(id, val) VALUES (4, 'fourth lookup') 

-- Convert ID String to individual IDs        
DECLARE @Xml xml
SELECT @Xml = CONVERT(xml,' <root><id>' + REPLACE(@IDString,',','</id><id>') + '</id></root>')

-- Join IDs to lookup table and return string
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(SELECT ',' + Val as [text()]
FROM (SELECT ID = Tab.rec.value('.','varchar(20)') FROM @Xml.nodes('/root/id') Tab(rec)) ids
JOIN #lookup ON ids.ID = #lookup.id
FOR XML PATH('')),2,1000) AS valuestring

--Cleanup, only used for example
DROP TABLE #lookup
```